# Query in firebase https function not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a query to realtime db in firebase https function but its not working. Here is my code

```
exports.fetchPost = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'GET') {
    res.status(403).send('Forbidden!')
  }
   let postId = JSON.stringify(req.query.postId) || 
   JSON.stringify(req.body.postId)
   cors(req, res, () => {
    admin.database().ref('items')
         .child(postId)
         .once('value', s => {
           console.log(s.val(), s)
           res.status(200).send(s.val())
         })
        .catch(e => res.status(500).send(e))
  })
})
```

I checked the logs. `s.val()` returns null, while `s` gives a firebase object that is unusable.

[image: Firebase function log]

Also, I am getting the following return on the request sent

[image: Error response being returned from the request]

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
admin.database().ref('items')
   .once('value', data => data.forEach(s => {
       s.key === postId ? console.log('success!') : console.log('not 
       found');
    }))
```

Try this part of your code that handles only with firebase. Tested here and worked, if it doesn't work, can you please show how your items are stored?

Comment: ok, will try this out, thanks for the response. I am still new to firebase, been using Parse server for a while now. What i intended to do is get just the single item.

Comment: Tested it, Didnt work. Same error as before. Plus there was an error in your code, you didn't specify the else part of the ternary operator. So i used an if statement.

Comment: Yes, i completely forgot about the else part there, i've edited the answer to be clearer, i hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you lots. This works, you just saved me a double trip to the server. I want to further optimize, what if i want to retrieve just that record, any suggestions?

Comment: I'm glad you could solve your problem. Unfortunately the read event 'value' passed as argumento to the ON or ONCE method returns all the data for the local that you've specified, including all the children data.

On non sql databases like Firebase's Database, you need to think different on how to structure your data, to prevent retrieving large amounts of data.

I recommend you the  Firebase's Youtube Channel: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=firebase to help you with this, there they have great up to date tutorials.